# Loading PostGIS layer from SQL query using PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

With PyQGIS I can load a vector layer from a `PostgreSQL/PostGIS` database :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "myBase", "myUser", "myPassword")
uri.setDataSource("mySchema", "myTable", "geom")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "myLayer", "postgres")
```

I want to apply a `SQL` query to load just a part of my features. With the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers) i've read i can add a simple `WHERE` clause :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "myBase", "myUser", "myPassword")
uri.setDataSource("mySchema", "myTable", "geom", "name like 'Example'")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "myLayer", "postgres")
```

But I'm not able to build a more complex syntax like `st_intersects`. For example :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "myBase", "myUser", "myPassword")
uri.setWkbType(QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon)
uri.setKeyColumn(u"idA")
myQuery = """SELECT a.name FROM public.tableA a INNER JOIN public.tableB b ON st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) WHERE a.name LIKE 'Example' AND b.name LIKE 'Something';"""
uri.setDataSource("mySchema", myQuery, "geom")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "myLayer", "postgres")
```

How can I use a full `SQL` query with a `QgsDataSourceUri` class (maybe with [setSql method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Data/QgsDataSourceUri.html#qgis.core.QgsDataSourceUri.setSql)) ?

Comment: Add the `idA` column. The Python2 `u` is no more necessary, Python3 is full UTF-8. If you haven't a unique column id in integer, bigint, etc., the layer is invalid.

Comment: Two essentials points that I didn't know : query must have an id column (in integer of course) and the geom. SQL query have to be surrounded by brackets and escapes quotes must be strictly observed. I post a full answer for other users. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A meticulous syntax must be respected, especially escaped quotes, and an id (integer) and a geom must appear in the query. Here is a full example with `st_intersects` :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "myBase", "myUser", "myPassword")
sql = 'SELECT a.idA, a.geom, a.name FROM public.tableA a INNER JOIN public.tableB b ON st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) WHERE a.name LIKE \'Example\' AND b.name LIKE \'Something\''
uri.setDataSource('', f'({sql})', 'geom', '', 'idA')
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'myLayer','postgres')
# Optional    
print (sql)
```

Comment: Since Python3.6, you can use f-string for pretty string formating : `uri.setDataSource('', f'({sql})', 'geom', '', 'idA')`.

Comment: Thanks, more readable syntax.