# setDataSource() not working with query PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

```
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection(aHost=self.db_conn.host, aPort=str(self.db_conn.port), aDatabase=self.db_conn.database, aUsername=self.db_conn.user, aPassword=self.db_conn.password)
        query = f"select target_geometry.target_geometry_id, st_setSRID(target_geometry.target_geometry_geometry, 4326) as target_geometry_geometry from flight_planning.target_geometry where target_geometry.target_geometry_id = {selection[0].text()};"
        uri.setDataSource('', f'({query})', 'target_geometry_geometry', '', 'target_geometry_id')
        #uri.setDataSource("", "target_geometry", "target_geometry_geometry", f'target_geometry.target_geometry_id = {selection[0].text()}', 'target_geometry_id')
        self.target_poly_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "target_geometry", "postgres")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.target_poly_layer)
```

The above code gives me this in the layer tree:
[image]

and in the properties, the source looks correct:
[image]

I have also tried the commented out line above as an alternative and it also does not work. If I don't try to use a query or a WHERE clause and just bring in the whole column from the table then it works just fine, but I only need part of the data.

I am using the answer from [pyqgis - Load a PostgreSQL/PostGIS layer from a SQL query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348833) as a reference.

Comment: Try without the semicolon **;** at the end of the query.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Wow that did it. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Monticolo convert that to an answer :-)

Comment: @J.Monticolo is it possible to pull my WHERE clause out of the formatted string and put it as an argument in the setDataSource function? I'm trying to do that but its not working.

Comment: @tbob: `f"select ... from ... {my_where_condition_as_str};"` and `my_where_condition_as_str = f"where target_geometry.target_geometry_id = {selection[0].text()};"`

Comment: @J.Monticolo I actually ended up doing this and it worked: uri.setDataSource('testing', 'selection_poly', 'selection_poly_polygon', "selection_poly.target_geometry_set_id = %s AND selection_poly.selection_poly_type = 'cluster'"%(self.set_selection,), 'selection_poly_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from @J.Monticolo I removed the semicolon in the query and it works now.

Comment: It's because QGIS doesn't execute straight "your query". Instead, it's encapsulate your query in "its" QGIS own query, similar to `SELECT * FROM (your query) as t` and other metadata QGIS needs to display it.